# how to return to the default product list if I don't want to filter anymore in Dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, filter

I making a feature filter product by category, but I have a problem that, I already filter the product successfully. As you know, after the product has been filtered, some products not that category will be hidden. I intend to add 1 option more in the filter that is to `get all listed products` (ie in this feature it will return the original product list), if I click on that option then all product list will be showed in the UI. How can I do that

I have code like this

```
const ProductList = ({
  products,
  category,
  sortPrice,
  searchTerm,
  loading,
  fetchCartRequest,
  fetchProductRequest,
  productsInCart
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userData");
    fetchProductRequest();
    fetchCartRequest(userId);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const [sortAndFilter, setSortAndFilter] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let results = products;
    results = searchByNameOrPrice(results, searchTerm);
    if (category) {
      results = filterByCategory(results, category)
    }
    if (sortPrice) {
      results = sortProductsByPrice(results, sortPrice)
    }
    setSortAndFilter(results);
  }, [category, products, sortPrice, searchTerm]);

  const searchByNameOrPrice = (products, searchTerm) => {
    return products.filter(
      (product) =>
        product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || searchTerm.includes(product.price)
    );
  };

  const filterByCategory = (products, category) => {
    return products.filter((item) => item.category === category);
  };

  const sortProductsByPrice = (products, sortPrice) => {
    if (sortPrice === PRICE_OPTION[0]) {
      return products.sort(
        (low, hight) => parseInt(low.price) - parseInt(hight.price)
      );
    }
    return products.sort(
      (low, hight) => parseInt(hight.price) - parseInt(low.price)
    );
  };



  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Loading />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {!!sortAndFilter && sortAndFilter.length > 0 ? (
          sortAndFilter.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <ProductItemContainer
                key={index}
                id={product.id}
                image={product.image}
                name={product.name}
                price={parseInt(product.price)}
              />
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <h4 className="title">Product list is empty!</h4>
          )}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I have an image like this for my filter

[image]

Comment: why dont you just clear all the filters on click of the button?

Comment: How can I do that, could you support for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to add an 'All' selection to your categories selector, you could handle this in your filterByCategory method.

i.e.

```js
  const filterByCategory = (products, category) => {
    return products.filter((item) => item.category === category || category === 'all');
  };
```

This could also be handled as an if statement to shortcut the filter.

```js
const filterByCategory = (products, category) => {
    if (category === 'all') return products;
    return products.filter((item) => item.category === category);
  };
```